# key down in .net

Tags: .net

How to validate iscontrolkeys in textbox keydown event in .net?

Answer (score 1):

[This msdn page should do the trick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx) - check the keypresseventsargs returned in the keypress or [this keydown page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(VS.80).aspx) should allow you to query the control keys (using the relevant .Net enum)

Answer (score 0):

in C#,

```
       private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
        {
            //Do some work
        }
    }
```

in VB.NET,

```
       Private  Sub textBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.ControlKey Then
                'Do some work'
            End If
       End Sub
```